# Select a text after an element in HTML by CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wanted to select the text after the **span** tag by **CSS** and give it a style that does not affect the span tag and only affects the text. In fact, I just want to style the **"Text to be selected"** text without affecting the span tag.

The style I want is a display: none , I actually want the phrase "Text to be selected" the style of the display change to **" none "** , but the span tag to be displayed and display style do not change.

```
<a>
  <span> Cricket </span> 
  Text to be selected // just this text select and change display to 'none'
</a>
```

With the font size trick, this mode can probably be simulated. To the .... tag, set the font size to zero and set the font size of the tag ... to ... or a numeric value, something like this will be simulated.

**A type of hack for simulation :**

With the font size trick, this mode can probably be simulated. To the a tag, set the font size to zero and set the font size of the tag span to initial or a numeric value, something like this will be simulated.

```
a {
   font-size: 0;
}
    
a span {
   font-size: initial; // or numeric value
}
```

Comment: why dont you wrap it vice verse, dont wrap Cricket, and wrap your targeted text with a span.

Comment: what kind of style you want to apply?

Comment: @Nicholas This structure must be the same, in fact the target element must be without a wrapper. And I want the text after span, its display value to be none.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The style I want is a display: none , I actually want the phrase "Text to be selected" the style of the display change to " none " , but the span tag to be displayed and display style do not change.

Comment: check the duplicate then

Comment: @TemaniAfif With the font size trick, this mode can probably be simulated. To the a tag, set the font size to zero and set the font size of the tag span to initial or a numeric value, something like this will be simulated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) for `span`

```css
a {
  color: red;
}

a span {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <span> Cricket </span> Text to be selected
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remember about **cascade** rules - order of declarations matters

```
  a{ color: red;}  
  span{ display: none}
```

first you paint `<a></a>` red,
than `<span></span>` even inside another element - you may style as you wish,  and it won't affect anything but `<span>`,
In this case if you change declarations order span will be affected with `color: red` as is inside `<a></a>`;

with pseudo-selector **`:not(span)`** you can style `<a></a>`  omitting `<span></span>` inside

```
  a:not(span){ color: yellow }  /* or whatever you want */
```

But, `<a></a>` is used as an link with href attribute, not for text styling. For text use `<p></p>`, please.

---- edit

I'm afraid I don't understand your added asks. `<a></a>` has many different states: `:link :hover :active :visited`
Each one state can be styled separately. Which change do you mean?

If you set `display: none` it never will be displayed, if you set `a{ font-size: 0}` element will be invisible and not clickable.

If you want `onchange` js event - it works with `<form>` elements, not with `<a></a>`, you may use another event from the [list](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Comment: The style I want is a display: none , I actually want the phrase "Text to be selected" the style of the display change to " none " , but the span tag to be displayed and display style do not change.